# Simplifications of the Elliptic integral $\displaystyle J_n(r)=\int^r_{r_0}\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}}$ for specific values of $n$.

Tags: elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

Consider an indefinite "elliptic integral”,
$$
J_n(r):=\int^r_{r_0}\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{f(x)}}, \quad f(x):=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3).
$$
where $r_0>0, n=1,0,−1$, and $x_{1,2,3}$ are roots of the cubic equation $()=0$.

I am interested in a case when $()=0$ has one real root $_1>0$ and two complex roots $_2$ and $_3$ (since it's a cubic equation, they are also complex conjugate, $_3=\bar{x_2}$).

**I want to know if $_{−1}$ can be written without imaginary number $$**, because this integral appears in a problem of physics, $_$ should be real. But, so far, I failed to make it. I write down what I faced:

I have tried an integration by substitution. In the present case, let $_2=+$ and thus $_3=\bar{x_2}=−$. Then we have $()=(−_1)((−)^2+^2)$.

Now, transform the variable from $$ to $$ with
$$
=_1+ \tan^2, :=\sqrt{(_1−)^2+^2}.
$$
After some manipulation, $_$ reduces to
$$
\frac{\sqrt{p}}{2}_()=\int\frac{(x_1+\tan^2y)^n {\rm d}y}{\sqrt{1−\sin^2\cos^2}},
$$
where $:=2(−(_1−))/$ and thus $0<<2$ by definition.

For $=0$ and $n=+1$, there is no problem: For $=0$, a software "Mathematica" returns
$$
\frac{\sqrt{p}}{2}_0()=\frac{1}{2}(2,\frac{A}{4}),
$$
where $(\phi,)$ is Elliptic integral of the first kind. For $=1$, Mathematica returns a combination of elliptic functions and elementary functions (I do not express them here, though).

Note that there is no imaginary number $i$ so far.

For $=−1$, however, integration returns a messy form with $i$:
[image]

where $\Pi(n,\phi,m)$ is incomplete Elliptic integral of the third kind.

**I guess there should be a simpler form of $_{−1}$ without $i$.**
Maybe the above transformation is not good for $_{−1}$?
Is there some identities that eliminate $i$?
I am not comfortable that in the messy form, because $\sqrt{A-4}$ appears, although $0<<2$.

I am beginner of elliptic integral, any comments are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Let $\pm \sqrt {1 - u^2} = (x - x_1 - p)/(x - x_1 + p)$, then
$$\int_{x_1 + p}^r \frac {dx} {x \sqrt {(x - x_1) ((x - a)^2 + b^2)}} =
\frac 1 {4 x_1 p^{3/2}} \int_{u_0}^1
 \frac {\pm ((x_1 - p) u^2 + 2 p) - 2 p \sqrt {1 - u^2}}
  {(1 - n u^2) \sqrt {1 - u^2} \sqrt {1 - m u^2}} du, \\
m = \frac 1 2 \left( 1 + \frac {a - x_1} p \right),
\quad n = -\frac {(x_1 - p)^2} {4 x_1 p},
\quad u_0 = \frac {2 \sqrt {(r - x_1) p}} {r - x_1 + p},$$
with the plus sign corresponding to $r > x_1 + p$ and the minus sign to $r <x_1 + p$. This gives $F$, $\Pi$ and an elementary function.

Comment: Thanks! How did you come up with the transformation? Just amazing for me...

Comment: Those are fairly standard steps in the theory of elliptic integrals. If we apply the substitution $v = (x - A)/(x - B)$, we get a quartic polynomial under the square root. Choosing $(A, B) = x_1 \pm p$ eliminates the $v^1$ and $v^3$ terms. The quartic becomes $(1 - v^2) (C^2 + v^2)$, so we take $u^2 = 1 - v^2$.

Comment: @Maxim Thank you. If you would like to post your answer, I can click your answer that was helpful.